CSP in react app created by `create-react-app`
I have react app created with create-react-app.
I started add CSP policies to my app. I have problem with my style-src part without using unsafe-inline. My all styles throw error in broswer connected with injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js which insert some styles and tags.
Someone know how to fix it to work with CSP?
My policy script-src 'self' http://127.0.0.1.
